# Weird links appear in Google Search despite website not having such content

Tags: wordpress, google-search, google-search-console

I have a website under development and I'm looking for help. There is something wrong, because there are weird links appearing in Google Search.

The website is using the latest Wordpress version, downloaded and installed from the official website of said platform.

It uses these plugins also installed from the plugin page within Wordpress:

```
ACF Content Analysis for Yoast SEO
Advanced Custom Fields PRO
All in one Favicon
Contact Form 7
Contact Form CFDB7
Hide Admin Bar
Password Protected
Remove Yoast SEO Comments
Yoast SEO
```

The website is hosted under a secured `Ubuntu 16.04` machine, protected with SSL and nobody, but me, has access to the machine.

The page is under development and so far only has one index page that consists of a couple images and paragraphs of texts.

**The problem described**

Technically, I have a couple real accessible links that have content behind them. Right now they're behind a password (a plugin I use to disable website while it's in development). Those are the default Wordpress links, and the index link, such as

`example.com/index.php/category/uncategorized/`

`example.com` and such other links.

What I can NOT understand is where do these links come from (view the picture, green are the links with actual content and red are the unknown links):

I'm aware of the fact I had deducted the domain earlier, but you can see the actual domain in the screenshot. Maybe that can help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BYIV.png

**The weird thing**

Note in the screenshot, these links date way back to 2013-2014. I know that using sitemaps, sitemap can tell a search engine when the link was originally indexed and whatnot. The domain itself was registered during early 2018.

These are the contents of the root of the server directory.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vebvY.png

Any help is very much appreciated. I am willing to provide all information necessary to solve this issue and determine where do these links are coming from.

Thanks.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that by googling those sentences written in those links, I'm getting rather spammy results. I'm not an expert when it comes to this.

I also have the website registered and verified, and have full rights in Google Webmasters and Search Console.

Comment: When I've had such issues in the past, it's been down to a hacked site. They are sneaky. My normal remedy would be to completely remove and replace the default WordPress install. From what you've described, though, it seems it's clean so I'd be inclined to suspect one of the plugins. While the site is in development I'd be inclined to set it to 'discourage search engines' too. 
If it's manageable, request webmaster to remove the URLs in question (if there are 1000s then that is hard), and replace all of the WP and plugin code with fresh downloads from the original sites. As a first step.

Comment: I will do that this evening,